# Dimension of integral schemes of locally finite type over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In Exercise 3.20 of *Algebraic Geometry*, Hartshorne makes several claims about the dimension of an integral scheme of finite type over a field. For instance, he claims that the dimension is equal to the dimension of the local ring at any closed point. I believe I understand how to solve this exercise, but I don't see why why need the scheme to be finite type, as opposed to merely locally finite type. Could anyone give me an example of such a scheme of locally-finite type, but not of finite type, such that its dimension is not equal to the dimension of its localization at a closed point?

Comment: Hartshorne talks about a scheme over $k$. In this case locally of finite type and finite type coincides (since there is just one open set in $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$).

Comment: @FredrikMeyer I don't think that is true. Whether or not a morphism is of finite type or merely locally finite type depends on whether the *domain* can be covered by finitely many sets, not the codomain, so $Spec(k)$ only having one open set shouldn't change anything. For instance, I think that the affine line with countably many origins is an integral scheme of locally finite type over $k$, but not of finite type.

Comment: Of course this works just as well for locally of finite type schemes: just take a finite type open set containing your point, and the local ring doesn't change. Hartshorne (as his paragraph on noetherian hypotheses indicates) isn't worried about always doing things in the greatest generality. Does he ever define "locally of finite type"?

Comment: @Relapsarian Thanks. That's what I thought, but I assumed I had made a mistake. He does define locally finite type, and it's used a couple of times in the exercises.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the scheme to be finite type. If $X$ is an integral scheme locally of finite type over a field $k$, then for all open affines $U = \mathrm{Spec}(A) \subset X$, $U$ is irreducible and dense in $X$ (because $U$ is open and $X$ irreducible) so $\dim(U) = \dim(\bar{U}) = \dim(X)$. Furthermore we may assume $A$ is finite-type over $k$ and apply all the relevant theorems like $\dim(A) = \mathrm{trdeg}_k(\mathrm{Frac}(A))$. In particular, $\dim(X) = \dim(\mathscr{O}_{X,P})$ for all closed points $P \in X$.